# Using or for matching regex

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I'd like to extract `foo` from either `-afooa-` or `-bfoob-` using regex.

I first tried this (using `boost`):

```
std::string input = "-afooa-";
boost::regex  re("-(?:a|b)(.*)(?:a|b)-");
boost::smatch what; 
bool isMatchFound = boost::regex_match(input, what, re); 

if (isMatchFound && what.size() == 2) 
{ 
    std::cout << what[1];
}
```

This works, but allows `-afoob-`....so I tried to update my regex and after reading regex documentation I felt like I needed a or condition with "non-marking parenthesis" and ended up with this regex `-(?:a(.*)a|b(.*)b)-` but then two matchs ar found `"foo"` and `""`...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As an option, you can use `-(a|b)foo\1-`

Comment: Would you please tag your question with type of regex flavor or programming language?

Comment: @revo: Done, howerer, I guess this is not specific to my programming language...

Comment: You posted a code block and asked about a RegEx. So I couldn't be wrong about that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a capturing group around the first `(a|b)` and then use a backreference:

```
-(a|b)(.*?)\1-
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dJ3rJ0/1). You will get the result in `what[2]` this time.

In C++, declare

```
boost::regex  re("-(a|b)(.*?)\\1-");
```

I also suggest using a lazy dot `.*?` in order to get the substring after the  `a` or `b` to the *first* occurrence of the next `a` or `b`.

Just FYI: `regex_match` will only match the *full* string. If you are looking for partial matches, use `regex_search`.

And for comleteness: *if you want to get the result into Group 1* (via `what[1]`), you need a *branch reset* grouping construct:

```
-(?|a(.*?)a|b(.*?)b)-
```

See the [Boost regex reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html#boost_regex.syntax.perl_syntax.branch_reset) and [a demo](https://regex101.com/r/eS3yU9/1).

Comment: Thanks! `-(?|a(.*?)a|b(.*?)b)-` did the trick. Could yo uexplain what's wrong with my original version (`-(?:a(.*)a|b(.*)b)-`)?

Comment: The `-(?:a(.*)a|b(.*)b)-` pattern matches `-`, then either of the two: 1) `a(.*)a` - `a` followed with any 0+ chars other than a newline up to the last `a` on the line capturing the substring in between `a`s into Group 1, or 2) `b(.*)b` - `b` followed with any 0+ chars other than a newline up to the last `b` on the line capturing the substring in between `b`s into Group 2. Thus, you needed to check which group matched. When using a branch reset, the group indexing resets from branch to branch and you get the first capturing group with Index 1 and the second one in Branch 2 with the same index.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the answer and the regex lesson ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The `*` allows for zero length matches. You might try a `+`, to require one or more (so `.+` would be one or more of any-character).